# Discord.py max_uses field is not working properly in create_invite() function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have following piece of code to invite users to a discord server. It creates an invitation link which I can then email someone. Problem is, the invitation link is supposed to work only once, but as per my testing, 2 or more users can use the same link to join the server. Am I not understanding the use of `max_uses=1`?

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    server = client.guilds[0]
    link = await server.text_channels[0].create_invite(max_uses=1)
    print(link)
```

Comment: Sure you are looking at the right invite link? Because I can't see anything wrong here...

Comment: Yes the link was same. I have even record of it in my email. I shared it with my friend and he was able to join the discord server.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the code itself is correct. However, the invite link is expired only if its used to join a new member to the channel.

I joined myself (developer of the bot) first to the channel via the link ... and then shared that same link to a friend, via which he was able to join as well. Once he (a new member to the channel) joined via the link, it got expired.